# multiple elements in .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to objects: object S and oject SD.

```
//form group startTime
formStart = $(fstart).clone();
s = $(d).clone();
    $(s).addClass('input-group date datetimepicker-s').html(startTime);

sd = $(d).clone();
    $(sd).addClass('input-group date datetimepicker-s').html(startDate);
```

And I want to put them in the same group on this way:

```
$(formStart).html(s,sd).prepend('<label>Begintijd</label>');
```

But maybe it is very obvious, this isn't working. 
My question is, is it possible to add multiple elements into .html() or is it possible to do this:

```
$(element).html().html();
```

Comment: `s` and `sd` are already jQuery objects, no need to wrap them in `$()` again.

Comment: $(element).append(s).append(sd)?

Comment: @oGeez thanks, same is for formStart. It is an object too already! I'll edit it in my code!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You shouldn't use `.html()` at all when you want to pass jQuery objects. Use [**`.append()`**](https://api.jquery.com/append/), instead, which accepts an array of elements or a variable number of arguments:

```
formStart.append(s, sd)
```

If you want to empty the parent element first (replicate the behavior of `.html()`), use [**`.empty()`**](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) (what surprise):

```
formStart.empty().append(s, sd)
```

---

Also note that `.clone` returns a jQuery object, so `formstart` is *already* a jQuery object and you should use `formStart` instead of `$(formStart)`. Same for `s` and `sd`. If you are not very familiar with jQuery's basics, I recommend to read the jQuery tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/.

Comment: Thankyou! This worked for me. I also saw another option: $(formStart).html(s.add(sd)); That worked too.. Which is a better option for it? I'll accept your answer soon!

Comment: @Drogon For sure using `append()` is better

Comment: @Drogon: According to the documentaiton, `.html` should not event work with jQuery objects (but it might). If you have DOM elements, then there is no reason to convert them to an HTML string first and let the browser parse the HTML string back to DOM elements again, if you can directly work with the DOM elements. If you want to make yourself more familiar with the DOM, see http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html. It's important to understand the relationship between JS, the DOM and HTML.

Comment: @FelixKling Actually i had deleted my answer after having a glance with the `.html()` doc, but it really works. http://jsfiddle.net/88uz9/ Why the jquery doc is not clear at this context..? Err... not at you :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy: There are a couple of methods that work with value not specified in the documentation. I don't know if the documentation is simply not up to date, or if they don't want to encourage the other user, but still want to support as a safe guard thingy. Who knows :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$(formStart).append(s,sd)
```

`append()` will not clear content of the target so you need to clear the target before appending the new content

```
$(formStart).empty().append(s,sd)
```

Comment: `append(e)` does not yield the same result as `.html(e)` as `.append()` does **not** clear the content of the target element but merely appends to it. You will need to use `.emtpy()` or similar before the append.